# Conditionally set a %let statement SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro, macro-variable

I was hoping someone could help with %if %then statements in SAS.

I want to conditionally set a macro variable so I was trying to do it this way:

```
%if &stress_test. = "Y" %then %let CURR_BOE = &BOE_ST.;
%if &stress_test. = "N" %then %let CURR_BOE = 0.0525;
```

Where &stress_test. is a macro variable already set. And &BOE_ST is a macro variable already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do %if-%then-%else Macro logic in open code, there are restrictions. See the blog post [Using %IF-%THEN-%ELSE in SAS programs](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/07/05/if-then-else-sas-programs/).

1. The %if-%then *must* be followed by a %do-%end block for the statements that you want to conditionally execute.
2. Nesting is not allowed.

Since you have to consecutive %if statements in your code with no %do block following it, SAS interprets this as nesting and both restrictions are violated.

**This gives an error:**

```
%let stress_test = N;

%if &stress_test. = Y %then %let CURR_BOE = 1;
%if &stress_test. = N %then %let CURR_BOE = 2;

%put &=CURR_BOE.;
```

**This does not give an error**

```
%let stress_test = N;

%if &stress_test. = Y %then %do;
   %let CURR_BOE = 1;
%end;
%else %do;
   %let CURR_BOE = 2;
%end;

%put &=CURR_BOE.;
```

Also, you could just wrap the whole thing into a macro and call that. Then you do not have the two restrictions mentioned.

```
%macro m;

%let stress_test = N;

%if &stress_test. = Y %then %let CURR_BOE = 1;
%if &stress_test. = N %then %let CURR_BOE = 2;

%put &=CURR_BOE.;

%mend m;

%m
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm finally understanding %if %then  a bit better. Thanks for all your help across various questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but I suspect your problem is not realizing that the SAS macro language is a text language. My guess is that the `&stress_test.` macro variable takes some value `Y` or `N`, NOT `"Y"` or `"N"`. There is a difference.

Therefore, I think all you need to do is this.

```
%if &stress_test. = Y %then %let CURR_BOE = &BOE_ST.;
%if &stress_test. = N %then %let CURR_BOE = 0.0525;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I 've made the updates but I get the error: ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.

Comment: See my answer above. Should be sufficient